# Can the sum of two divergent integrals yield a convergent integral?

Tags: calculus

Given:

$f(x) + g(x) \neq 0$

$\int_a^b f(x) dx $ diverges

$\int_a^b g(x) dx $ diverges

$a$ and $b$ can be real numbers or $\pm\infty$

Find $f$ and $g$ such that:

$$\int_a^b (f(x)+g(x)) dx = L$$

for some finite $L$.

I really can't seem to think of any examples asides from $f+g=0$. Is there a solution to this at all?

Comment: Try the case $f+g=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx $ diverges and $\int_a^{b} h(x)dx$ converges with $h \neq 0$. Take $g=h-f$
$$\int_a^b (f(x)+g(x)) dx =\int_a^{b} h(x)dx$$ is convergent.
Also, $\int g$ is divergent.

Example: $f(x)=\frac  1 {x-a}, h(x)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have some $f$ firstly, and then you let $g$  be $-f$ outside a finite subset $F$ of $[a,b]$. For any $x\in F$, you can take any values for $g$ such that $f(x)+g(x)\neq 0$.